# Running QEMU VM, Windows Host. Need to increase RAM for Guest VM

Tags: windows, qemu

Running guest Ubuntu VM on Windows Host (QEMU).
Installed a lot of libraries here in Ubuntu and much scared too "break" vm.
Need to increase RAM for Guest VM.
Tried to google the thing out, but there no clear solution for me yet.
Kindly advise

Answer (score 0):

Use the -m command line option. For 128 kilobytes you would use -m 128K For 512 megabytes you would use -m 512M For 4 gigs, you would use -m 4G